# File SHA256 checksum failed, but OK on reboot

Tags: windows, sha256

I downloaded the Windows installer (.exe) for ImageMagick via http (both http and ftp downloads are provided [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)).

Upon executing the file, Windows SmartScreen displays a banner across the screen saying "Running this app might put your PC at risk", so I decide to verify the published SHA256 checksum using the md5deep package.

Turns out the downloaded file doesn't match the published checksum. I then tried downloading the file via FTP. This one worked. No SmartScreen warnings, no checksum errors.

I tried downloading the http version a few more times. Once again, the SmartScreen warning is back and checksum doesn't match.

The strange thing is, upon rebooting Windows, all of the previously corrupted files (the ones downloaded via http) suddenly match the checksum, and also, SmartScreen no longer displays the warning.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Could you possibly share the name of the open source program you are referring to? This could help in checking if there is indeed an issue with the checksum on other systems.

Comment: Sure, ImageMagick.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: "Running this app might put your PC at risk" and "SHA256 checksum" have nothing to do with each other. The checksum checks if the download was OK, but says nothing about it harming your computer or not. I would say that a malware that failed the checksum is usually safer because the download is corrupt and it may not even be a valid executable.

Answer (score 1):

@ThatGuy Lets start by re-downloading the http and ftp links again now we can upload them to [VirusTotal.com](http://VirusTotal.com) while you are uploading the files we should come up with the MD5 hashs of the files, after you have found the MD5s you should Google them to see if anything comes back with the same MD5 you need to Google them with quotes and without. If everything comes back all okay then you have nothing to worry about.

Note that Googling the SHA256 may not return anything which happens alot when you search for them.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT:** Everything following is only part of my assumptions about this incident. Without further details of it nobody can tell you exactly what happened.

What browser are you using? I know that some browsers don't safe the file immediately but create a temp file while downloading. It may be that the change from this tempfile to the normal file was not finished (perhaps because of a writelock), and so the checksums where different.

As you rebooted your system, this process may have come to an end, so the checksums got right after.  (A little offtopic: may you explain why you tried to execute potentially harmfull files again after a reboot?)

The SmartScreen thing is AFAIK allways showing when executing files downloaded from the web, except for some defined 'good' pages. The file gets flaged, so Windows always knows to ask first. 
I have expirienced that a file downloaded over ftp doesn't get this flag and because of this can be executed without warning.

In general I would assume that someone with server access would change both (the ftp and http download files) to the malicious one and may also change the given checksums. But not even I would count on that fact.